# ksql table not showing data

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I am following the link below to learn ksql and connect.

https://github.com/confluentinc/demo-scene/blob/master/build-a-streaming-pipeline/demo_build-a-streaming-pipeline.adoc#inspect-topics

I successfully set up the debezium Kafka connector to talk to SQL Server.
[image]

I then created a table as

```
create table tbl_BPATag(id int primary key, Tag varchar) with(kafka_topic='localhost.dbo.BPATag', value_format='avro');
```

Following the table creation, I issued

```
select id, tag from tbl_BPATag emit changes;
```

Then updated and inserted records in the base table but KSQL select is not showing the changes.

I don't know what I am doing wrong?

**UPDATE 1**
[image]

**UPDATE 2**

```
{
 "name": "bp",
 "config": {
     "connector.class" : "io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerConnector",
     "tasks.max" : "1",
     "database.server.name" : "localhost",
     "database.hostname" : "localhost",
     "database.port" : "1433",
     "database.user" : "sa",
     "database.password" : "Password123*",
     "database.dbname" : "BP",
     "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers" : "localhost:9092",
     "database.history.kafka.topic": "schema-changes.bp" ,
     "database.whitelist":"bp",
     "table.whitelist":"dbo.BPAWorkQueue,dbo.BPAWorkQueueItem,dbo.BPAWorkQueueItemTag,dbo.BPATag"

     }
 }
```

Comment: Please show that data actually exists in the localhost.dbo.BPATag topic

Comment: Thanks..Please see the new images added below UPDATE

Comment: You need to extract out the after field, otherwise need to define a table over the whole Debezium event format

Comment: In particular, seems like you're missing the `transforms.unwrap.type` from the example in your own Debezium configuration (can you please show that too?)

Comment: @OneCricketeer , I tried select after->id from tblbpatag emit changes; but get
Line: 1, Col: 8: SELECT column 'AFTER' cannot be resolved.
Regarding transforms.unwrap.type , I can see this as part of SQL Server properties https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/connectors/sqlserver.html

Comment: The transform is for all Debezium connectors (its mentioned in the github page you linked), and you cannot select a field that's not part of your table schema. Again, please show your Debezium connector configuration

Comment: @OneCricketeer, Please see the update 2

Comment: Thanks. Did you read what that transform actual does? Any reason you're not following the github guide exactly?